# Are there any ui automation tools that allow you to change/add elements to a window?

Tags: winapi, selenium, automation, ui-automation

With selenium, we can get/change/add html elements from/to a web page.

But what about win32 based applications?

All the ui automation tools allow you to get elements of windows and verify the content. And they can also simulate mouse and keyboard events.

But are there any ui automation tools that allow you to change/add elements to a window?
Or are there any other tools/APIs available for that purpose?

Comment: How would you expect that to work?

Comment: It works easily for a web page thanks to "dynamic HTML", the fact that the whole UI is described in a read/write model (the DOM). There's no such thing for general Win32 applications. That's not really related to UI-automation, or selenium. You could do 'some things' if you inject some code into the target application. But that's not automation, that's hacking, and not an easy task... (google for CreateRemoteThread)

Comment: Have you tried Rational Functional Tester http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/functional/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an arbitrary Win32 application, of course not.  The question assumes that the UI framework for the app supports runtime modification, and most don't.  (That even assumes that the app actually *has* a UI framework.)

Answer (score 0):

There are many commercial tools for non web applications. Open source examples would be AutoIt, Twin, Sikuli..........